# Complex Lookup With Matching With Inclusive/Exclusive

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**EDITED**

After being asked for a more specific example, I created the example below:

[image]

I need a way to correctly assign values (**particularly those on the boundaries**) without building repeated if statements. My goal is to allow my users to change the ranges on excel and a user defined formula in vba would allocate the correct category.

**EDITED Dropped original question**

Comment: Why needs 200 to be `4` if it is included in `[200,Inf)` which should be 5?

Comment: Would be much easier to follow if you used the standard `>`, `<` , `>=`, `<=` notation.  However, if you want a VBA solution it's typically a good idea to post what you already tried an explain the problem you had with that code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are right. But the problem I have remains the same in that ranges `**are not monotonically increasing or decreasing**`. The solution would be the same

Comment: Why is the (non)regularity of the buckets a problem?

Comment: Because I cannot use `index(lookup_range,MATCH)` and it's impossible to do this for 30 ranges with serial if statements.

Comment: @J.Doe. Then you chose a bad example. Please show an example data that shows the actual issue. Because the example data you show can be handled correctly with the shown formula. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You just need to recalculate the borders where you lookup with match (Column G). And add a tiny number eg `+0.000000000001` if there is a `<` sign instead of a `<=`. The green values can be changed by the user the rest is calculated by formulas.

Note that if you change the `<=` or `<` signs it automatically changes the buckets `(` and `[` too.

[image]

Use these formulas and pull them down.

- C2 `=INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$7,1),1)`
- E2 `=IF(I2="<","(","[") & H2 & "," & L2 & IF(K2="<",")","]")`
- G2 `=IF(I2="<",H2+0.000000000001,H2)`
- K2 `=IF(I3="<","<=","<")`
- L2 `=H3`